# Can a multiclassed sorcerer/warlock use Quickened Spell to cast Green-Flame Blade and then use the Thirsting Blade feature to get 3 attacks on a turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, attack, sorcerer, metamagic

Can a multiclassed sorcerer-warlock use the Quickened Spell metamagic to cast a spell like *green-flame blade* as a bonus action, and then use the Thirsting Blade warlock feature to make 2 more attacks on the same turn?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### This works but it requires your bonus action *and* action

The Thirsting Blade Invocation states:

> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, **whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.**

The Thirsting Blade Invocation requires you to take the Attack action. Simply making an attack does not count as doing this, as discussed in the following questions: "[Can you combo attacks with the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96206)" and "[What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781)".

When you cast the *green-flame blade* spell (even if you do not quicken it) you are not taking the Attack action, instead you are taking the Cast a Spell action. What you can do is the following:

1. Cast Quickened *green-flame blade* (attacking a creature).
2. Take the Attack action, allowing you to attack twice with your pact weapon.

Another option is the following:

1. Take the Attack action, allowing you to attack twice with your pact weapon.
2. Cast Quickened *green-flame blade* (attacking a creature).

You would make three attacks total using up both your action and bonus action (and some  sorcery points). Note that you *can* move between the two attacks you make with the Attack action, this is because the section on "[Moving Between Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingBetweenAttacks)" states:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

The third option of having the Quickened *green-flame blade* occur in-between the attacks of your Attack action is more up to your GM than anything else, and is discussed in the question "[Can you break up your Attack action for a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72888)"