# Can I use the bonus action granted by the Charger feat to cast Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, damage, attack

Is it possible to use *Booming Blade* as part of my charger feat attack? Or is it separate? If so, what would my attack damage calculation be (assuming I'm using a greatsword and have Great Weapon Master and utilizing the -5/+10?)

Comment: Welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about us :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what your question is. Are you just asking if your build with charger and great weapon master feats will give you that damage output on a successful hit?

Comment: Do the charger and great weapon fighting feats work with booming blade, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Shawn, it looks like you have accidentally created two account which makes the prosess a lot more cumbersome (such as edits having to go through review). You should follow the directions [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged.

Comment: I made a pretty big edit, but based on your text, I think this may be what you're asking. If you disagree, please edit or you can roll it back!

Comment: Related to the overhauled question: [Can you combo attacks with the Booming Blade cantrip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96206/can-you-combo-attacks-with-the-booming-blade-cantrip?rq=1)

Comment: @Rykara Definitely related, but definitely not a duplicate (as I understand the current question state.)

Answer (score 17):

The [Charger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/charger) feat description reads, in part:

> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make
> one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature.

*—Player's Handbook* ch. 6

[*Booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) is a cantrip (a spell). Its spell description states, in part:

> **Casting time:** 1 action
>
> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon.

*—Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* ch. 4

The Charger feat description does not state that you can cast a spell with your bonus action using this feat. Even though making a melee weapon attack is part of casting *booming blade*, it is still considered casting a spell. Furthermore, the cantrip's casting time is one action, not one bonus action.

**By the rules, a PC cannot cast *booming blade* using the bonus action granted by the Charger feat.**

(Note: links require the appropriate access in D&D Beyond)

**Addendum**: I reviewed the OP's original question before it was edited by another user. The OP asked if it was possible "to make two attacks, one for booming blade and the other as a bonus attack for charging." The answer is no, not in the same turn, as the Charger feat requires to use your action to Dash in order to be able to attack using a bonus action. Of course a fighter using Action Surge would be the exception to this.

Comment: If you *really* wanted to, this is also supported in [an unofficial ruling](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/885611352990941185) by Jeremy Crawford: "The Charger feat lets you make a melee weapon attack or shove someone. It doesn't let you cast a spell."